# "HTTP" URIs (HTTP Upgrade mechanism) support in OkHttp

Tags: okhttp

As far as I understand this isn't supported in OkHttp 2.0. I have tried it with no luck so far...

Are there any plans to support this in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

No plans at the moment. Open an issue in the projects issue tracker to start the conversation!